# How to undo rm -rf .git?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on project which have git branch **master**.
I also cloned git repository in my project it's branch name is **git-clone-branch**.
I wanted to remove ***git-clone-branch*** *(only branch not files)*.
I used `rm -rf .git` but by mistake `rm -rf .git` applied on ***master*** branch and it removed entire *Git repository*.

**How to restore Git repository?**

Comment: `rm -rf .git` has nothing to do with any branch. It is not a git command. It simply blows away the entire Git repository in the directory where you are when you say it. It throws the invisible git folder in the trash and empties the trash, figuratively speaking. You cannot "undo" it unless you happen to have made a backup of your hard drive very recently.

Comment: As @Joshua said in their answer, make a new clone and start again on your local machine. Hopefully, you did not have any local changes in that sandbox!

Answer (score 1):

The command rm -rf has nothing to do with git and you just deleted that .git directory on your local machine. The best course of action is probably just to clone the entire repository again and all the pushed code and branches will be returned to you